# How do i drag multiple rows using vue.draggable?

Tags: html, vuejs2, draggable

I wanted to drag multiple table data in a row instead of just a single td tag. In other words, when i drag either columns, i want to drag both the "Random" and "name" column together.

```
<table id="app">
  <tr>
    <th>Random</th>
    <th>name</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>    
      <draggable v-model="items">
        <transition-group name="list-complete">
          <div v-for="item in items"
               v-bind:key="item.message"
               class="list-complete-item">
            {{ item.message }}
          </div>
        </transition-group>
      </draggable>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div v-for="item in items" class="list-complete-item">
        {{ item.name }}
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried shifting and playing around with the draggable tag and the transition-group tag but nothing seems to work.

Please help. :(

Here is my jsfiddle code -> 
https://jsfiddle.net/wusprtnL/63/

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by Sortable nor by Vue.draggable. So there are no combination of options that will make irt work. Reference: https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable/issues/1049

Answer (score 0):

Right now this is supported as a plugin by sortable, but the plugin has not been integrated in vue.draggable.

https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/649

Comment: is it supported now?